# Scala keeping first two elements of a tuple depending on the third one

Tags: scala

I'm a beginner with Scala. I have a `List[(Int, Int, Int)]`, what I want is to have `List[(Int, Int)]` (with the first two Ints) if the the third `Int` is greater than 0. I guess I need to integrate `list.map(x => (x._1, x._2))` with a `case` or `if` statement??
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

To combine a `map` and a `filter`, use `collect`:

```
list.collect {
  case (a, b, c) if c > 0 => (a, b)
}
```